# SQL Injection tool (Mac OS X)

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, macos

Do you know any software for searching (analyze) SQL injection (on website) from Snow Leopard ?

I have found some that can run from Linux or Windows.

I understand that most Linux (console) applications could be run under Mac Os x. But is there any GUI based software for that purpose ?

Comment: Is there any reason you must run it native on mac? I'd suggest just installing backtrack in a virtual machine and using sql map from it. Backtrack has loads of other useful tools as well.

Comment: Or just boot BackTrack off a live disc, and mount a partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Map is probably the best tool out there. It is on the command line, however, I did find this [GUI](http://code.google.com/p/gui-for-sqlmap/) for it. I haven't used it, but hopefully it will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

WebCruiser Web Vulnerability Scanner for Mac OS X 10.7+, an effective and convenient web penetration testing tool that will aid you in auditing your website!

WebCruiser can find the following web vulnerabilities currently:
- GET SQL Injection(Int, String, Search)
- POST SQL Injection(Int, String, Search)
- Cross Site Scripting(XSS)
WebCruiser provide a HTTP Request resend tool (or call it HTTP repeater) and a Cookie tool also.